# Mysql how to help cleanse data, specifically if contains text remove

Tags: mysql, select

I have a column as:

| Size |
| --- |
| 75cl |
| 70im |
| 7im |
| 30cim |
| 30clim |

And I need to convert the text to numbers but conditionally:

| Size |
| --- |
| 75cl |
| 70 |
| 7 |
| 30 |
| 30cl |

Where the size column includes "im" then I just want to return the numbers.

I have tried to write a few queries like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(LTRIM(RTRIM(size))) from tbl_size;
```

To determine how many rows I need to cleanse but I am a bit stuck on conditionally displaying the rows:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN size = '70im' THEN '70' etc
```

But I have 3,000 distinct values to accomodate and I am a bit stuck as to the best way to do this.
Any advice is appreciated, I am using MySQL.

Comment: `SELECT TRIM(TRAILING 'im' FROM size)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this sanely is to use regular expressions (regexes)! [This](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) is a great site and they have an excellent [quick start](https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) and other tutorials. This is StackOverflow's [`What does this regex mean`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) "reference" (aka "canonical") questions page - it's a great FAQ resource.

EDIT: Answer completely changed!

All of the code below is available on the fiddle [<s>here</s>](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=59c8bce8fc2dfce81780f2e32958007b) [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2195be29bf9c620757014059d26fd3b5).

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  measure VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL
);
```

Populate the table:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES
('75cl'),
('70im'),
('7im'),
('30cim'),
('30clim');
```

Then run the following code:

```
--
-- MySQL code
--

SELECT
  measure AS m,
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(measure, '^[0-9]+') AS num,
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(measure, '^[0-9]+cl|^[0-9]+') AS rex_str


--  LENGTH(CONCAT('xyz', REGEXP_SUBSTR(measure, '^[0-9]+'))) AS strlen,
 
--  (LENGTH(CONCAT('xyz', REGEXP_SUBSTR(measure, '^[0-9]+'))) - 2)
 
--  SUBSTR
--  (
--    (CONCAT('xyz', REGEXP_SUBSTR(measure, '^[0-9]+'))) FROM
--    (LENGTH(CONCAT('xyz', REGEXP_SUBSTR(measure, '^[0-9]+'))) - 2) FOR 2
--  )

FROM                                                                
  test;
```

Result (some extra fields left in to show train of thought - also, check out the PostgreSQL code on the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2195be29bf9c620757014059d26fd3b5)):

```
     m  num   rex_str
  75cl   75      75cl
  70im   70      70
   7im    7       7
 30cim   30      30
30clim   30      30cl
```

Regex pattern explained (`'^[0-9]+cl|^[0-9]+'`):

- `^` - a metacharacter indicating the start of the line
- `[0-9]` - the square brackets are indicative of what is called a character class - this will recognise the digits 0-9
- `+` - this means one or more occurrences of the preceding item in the regex - in this case, the digits
- `cl` of the string - corresponds to the literal text "cl" - will pick out `cl` and only `cl` - not the `im` part of the string
- `|` - finally, the pipe character is regexes mean `OR` - so we can chain different patterns as required
- the second half of the pattern picks up strings that **don't** contain `cl` - or centilitres when written normally. Because we have only specified the digits, the `im` string disappears

This will work well if you only have a few strings that you wish to match (i.e. `cl`, `xx`, `yy`...) but you may require an alternative strategy should circumstances change.

Regexes are powerful tools and well worth getting to know - they are tricky and can be incredibly complex - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression) about emails. There's tradeoff between power/complexity and efficiency (checkout this [6,900 character monster](http://www.ex-parrot.com/%7Epdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) to match emails).

You should also be aware that it is virtually **always** better to use your RDBMS's inbuilt functions in preference to regexes - they are powerful, but with that power comes an overhead - you shouldn't lose sight of that fact! For a cogent analysis of potential non-technical issues, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/202528/470530).

Comment: Really appreciate the detail, will give this a go.  Thanks.

Comment: No problem - and get back to me if you require anything further. If you're happy with the answer, you could always mark it correct! :-)

Answer (score 0):

`IF(size LIKE '%im', 0+size, size)` seems to suffice.

Here are 3 test cases, using a SET value for simplicity.

```
mysql> SET @size := '70cim';

mysql> SELECT IF(@size LIKE '%im', 0+@size, @size);
+--------------------------------------+
| IF(@size LIKE '%im', 0+@size, @size) |
+--------------------------------------+
| 70                                   |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                   |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '70cim' |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @size := '123cl';

mysql> SELECT IF(@size LIKE '%im', 0+@size, @size);
+--------------------------------------+
| IF(@size LIKE '%im', 0+@size, @size) |
+--------------------------------------+
| 123cl                                |
+--------------------------------------+

mysql> SET @size := '987';

mysql> SELECT IF(@size LIKE '%im', 0+@size, @size);
+--------------------------------------+
| IF(@size LIKE '%im', 0+@size, @size) |
+--------------------------------------+
| 987                                  |
+--------------------------------------+
```

If it is more complex than simply checking for ending in 'im', you may need a `CASE` expression instead of a simple `IF` function.

(I see that -cim and -clim should work differently; please elaborate on how those are distinguished, and check on what other odd-ball cases there are.)